# Print sched queue with human readable time

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, sched

I want to print the queue from sched scheduler with human-readable time.
But whatever I try I get weird results despite the event are executed in proper time and order.

How can achieve that?

### Current code

```py
scheduler = sched.scheduler(timefunc=time.time)

# Add some events into a scheduler

def executing_at_message(event):
    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(event.time)
    print(f"{date.hour}:{date.minute}: {event.action.__doc__}")

for event in scheduler.queue:
    executing_at_message(event)
```

Comment: What results do you get? Code seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't changed anything, apart from adding the actual jobs, and this seems to work fine.

```py
import sched
from datetime import datetime
import time

scheduler = sched.scheduler(timefunc=time.time)

def main():
    """Do the main thing"""
    time.sleep(3)
    print('Done main')

def other():
    """Do the other thing"""
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Done other')

scheduler.enter(3, 2, main)
scheduler.enter(2, 1, other)

def executing_at_message(event):
    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(event.time)
    print(f"{date.hour}:{date.minute}:{date.second} {event.action.__doc__}")

for event in scheduler.queue:
    executing_at_message(event)
```

output:

```sh
22:41:45 Do the other thing
22:41:46 Do the main thing
```

Comment: I am really sorry yes this code Is working as expected, i was using enterabs instead of enter so event time was an amount of seconds to wait instead of timestap